# We do not work {on, for, in} holidays. Which is correct?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I do not understand what should be the correct preposition for this sentence. EVERY option seems suitable.

> We do not work _____ holidays.
>
> a) on
>   
> b) for
>   
> c) in

Comment: or just leave the blank a blank

Comment: The answer is 'a', We do not work **_on_** holidays.

Answer (score 1):

"On" is the only acceptable option of the three choices you listed.  You could use "for" but this implies something radically different from what I think you mean.

Comment: There are cases where any of the three can in fact be valid here. *We do not work on holidays* — either we do not work on days which are designated holidays, or we do not work on our time off. *We do not work for holidays* — the purpose of our work is not to enjoy holidays. *We do not work in holidays* — we do not factor (*work in*) holiday time in, say, a project plan. This is why context is essential.